# Android - RuntimeException - ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, classcastexception, runtimeexception

My problem is that when I run my app on the android emulator the app starts up but after login, the app quickly crashes and displays the popup: "Unfortunately,  has stopped." I have looked through the code and have searched the internet thoroughly for an answer. Yes I am a newbie at android development. I have looked at the errors that have been generated by LogCat but do not know the problem and where to find it based on the errors I received.

Here is logcat:

```
11-01 08:09:37.650: W/dalvikvm(2382): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d02b20)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382): Process: com.pozs.myappz, PID: 2382
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pozs.myappz/com.pozs.myappz.Tabbedmaincontroller}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshGridView$InternalGridViewSDK9 cannot be cast to com.penq.utils.LoadMoreGrid
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshGridView$InternalGridViewSDK9 cannot be cast to com.penq.utils.LoadMoreGrid
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at com.pozs.myappz.GridFragment.onCreateView(GridFragment.java:70)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
11-01 08:09:37.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     ... 11 more
```

The following is the GridFragment.java:

```
package com.pozs.myappz;

import java.util.ArrayList;

<...other import here deleted...>

import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase;
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase.OnRefreshListener2;
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshGridView;
import com.penq.utils.LoadMoreGrid;
import com.penq.utils.LoadMoreGrid.OnLoadMoreListener;
import com.pozs.Vo.FeedsVo;
import com.pozs.peak.adapter.GridAdapter;
import com.pozs.peak.utils.CommonUtils;

public class GridFragment extends Fragment {
public static ArrayList<FeedsVo> abcd;

private GridAdapter ga;
private String m_urlResp, m_userIdVal;
private Bundle m_bundle;
private String profileName, imageUrl, m_hearts, m_likes, m_ImageID,
        m_videoUrl, m_swebLinkUrl;
private ProgressDialog pDlg;
private Context m_context;
private Boolean m_resultStatus, m_isHeartbyMe = false,
        m_isLikebyMe = false,isDone=false;
private TextView m_tvNoData, m_tvTitle;
    int pageval = 1;
private PullToRefreshGridView mPullRefreshGridView;
private LoadMoreGrid mGridView;
private ImageView m_ivFollower;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feedpage, container, false);
    m_context = GridFragment.this.getActivity();
    abcd = new ArrayList<FeedsVo>();
    pDlg = new ProgressDialog(m_context);

    m_bundle = this.getArguments();
    m_userIdVal = m_bundle.getString("userId");

    m_tvNoData = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_nodata);
    m_tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fd_tvTitle);

    mPullRefreshGridView = (PullToRefreshGridView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.feedgrid);
    mGridView = (LoadMoreGrid) mPullRefreshGridView.getRefreshableView(); <--Line 70 as it is indicated in logcat
    m_ivFollower = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fd_ivFollow);

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(m_context.getAssets(),
            "helvetica.ttf");
    m_tvTitle.setTypeface(font);
    ga = new GridAdapter(abcd, getActivity());

    mGridView.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {

        public void onLoadMore() {
            feedtask Feed = new feedtask();
            Feed.execute();

        }
    });

<...other codes here deleted...>        

    if (myappz.m_FeedsScreen == "" || myappz.m_FeedsScreen == null) {
            pageval = 1;
            feedtask Feed = new feedtask();
            Feed.execute();
            mGridView.setAdapter(ga);
            abcd.clear();

            Log.e("GridFragment", "Resume Called");

        myappz.m_sFollowerId = null;
        }
    }

}
```

The above seems ok to me too, for sure, I missed something here. Any help is apprecated.

Thanks!

Comment: mPullRefreshGridView.getRefreshableView() cannot be cast to LoadMoreGrid.

Comment: Thanks. perhaps because of different type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is used to indicate that the application’s code has attempted to cast a specific object to a class of which it is not an instance.

For example, an `Integer` object cannot be casted to a `String` object.

in your case you tried to cast  `mPullRefreshGridView` to `LoadMoreGrid`, which is not permitted..

when trying to cast an object of a class into another class, Ensure that the new type belongs to one of its parent classes.